# how to force find to recursively search subdirectories

Tags: find

I run this command

```
find -iname *something*
```

It normally searches in subfolders but if I have a file that matches the criteria in the working directory it only reports it and stops.
I'm thinking to write a function that first searches sub folders in current directory than issue many find commands for each of them but I feel there should be an easier way... Actually I think it should be the default behavior, so maybe I have something wrong in some setup file?

Comment: do you have it aliased or hidden with a function? `alias find` and `declare -f find` output would clarify the situation

Comment: What happens when you add a dot after find - `find . -iname something` ?

Answer (score 6):

Does *something* include a glob that is being interpreted by the shell? That would cause the expanded filename to be passed to the find command.

For example if you run `find -iname *.txt` with a file in the current directory called **file.txt** then the resulting command after shell expansion would be `find -iname file.txt`.

To avoid this pitfall you can escape the glob to send the literal string to the find command with `find -iname '*.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

If the subfolders are behind symbolic links you have to use the -L option. Try

```
find -L . -iname '*something*'
```

According to the find man pages

> If  -L  is in effect and find discovers a symbolic link to a subdirectory during its search, the subdirectory pointed to by the symbolic link will be searched.